# How do I login with Twitch/Discord/Google in a popup window that passes the access token back to the website and logs the user in without refreshing?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, authentication, nuxt.js

So what I want is that if the user clicks on "Login with Twitch" (or any other service) a new window pops up and shows the "Authorize" page. When the user authorizes the application, the window closes and passes the access token, that is located in the redirect url as a parameter, back to the website and fire a function to login the user without refreshing the website.

I use Nuxt and an Express API server.

Here is a website that has this login procedure that I want to achieve: https://mee6.xyz/

Comment: I would have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Comment: @super I think that could work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Nuxt and Express API but I can explain anything you need.

What you need is to `create popup window` that open your authorization link.

Popup window on success authorization will redirect you to `redirect url` where you can proceed data and respond with your server.

With cross-origin requests you can not access your child popup but what you can do is to send html response where you `close current window (popup) on success`.
Example of what you need to do below:

JavaScript

```js
let url = 'your authorization link'
let params = 'popup window parameters'
let target = 'authorization target'

window.open(url, target, params)
```

HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<script>
    // Close this window (popup)
    window.close()
</script>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```